# Find the nearest date and time from the list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used this code to find the closest time in dateTimes list to local time.
Everything works fine.
for example

It is now 23:00 and the closest time in the list is 22:58.
I want it not to show the previous hours as the nearest hour

```dart
void main() {
  final dateTimes = <DateTime>[
    DateTime(2020, 8, 1),
    DateTime(2020, 8, 5),
    DateTime(2020, 7, 13),
    DateTime(2020, 7, 18),
    DateTime(2020, 8, 15),
    DateTime(2020, 8, 20)
  ];
  final now = DateTime(2020, 7, 14);
  
  final closetsDateTimeToNow = dateTimes.reduce(
      (a, b) => a.difference(now).abs() < b.difference(now).abs() ? a : b);

  print(closetsDateTimeToNow); // 2020-07-13 00:00:00.000
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897661/flutter-get-closest-timestamp-to-now-from-list Check this link

Comment: @julemand101 Please guide me if possible

Answer (score 0):

```
 void sortDateFunction() {
    ///
    /// Example DateTime List
    ///
    final List<DateTime> dates = [
      DateTime.now(),
      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1)),
      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 2)),
      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 3)),
      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 4)),
      DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1)),
      DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 2)),
      DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 3)),
      DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 4)),
    ]
      ..shuffle() /// Shuffle list bc it's already looks like sorted
      ..toList();

    final List<DateTime> sortedList = dates..sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));

    for (final DateTime date in sortedList) {
      print(date);
    }
  }
```

**Output:**

```
2023-12-23 17:33:10.273
2023-12-24 17:33:10.273
2023-12-25 17:33:10.273
2023-12-26 17:33:10.273
2023-12-27 17:33:10.273
2023-12-28 17:33:10.273
2023-12-29 17:33:10.273
2023-12-30 17:33:10.273
2023-12-31 17:33:10.273
```

Comment: OP asked for the nearest time, and sorting doesn't directly find that.  Moreover, sorting does a lot of extra work and is O(n log n) whereas finding the nearest `DateTime` should be O(n).  Incidentally, since `DateTime` objects are already `Comparable`, you don't need to pass the explicit comparison callback to `.sort()`.